# My code crashes if it tries to play a mp3 file, works fine for wav files

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, audio, xna, soundeffect

All my sound clips are in mp3, so I do not really feel like translating them tp wav.
If I try to play a mp3 file I get a exception, but the code works fine for .wav files.
I figure there must be a way to play mp3 files.

```cs
Stream s = TitleContainer.OpenStream("sounds/bag.mp3");

// throws a exceptio if its a mp3 file
SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(s);
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
effect.Play();
```

Answer (score 2):

It is by design - `SoundEffect.FromStream` only works with wave files. As [per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.fromstream.aspx):

> The Stream object must point to the head of a valid PCM wave file.
>   Also, this wave file must be in the RIFF bitstream format.
>
> The audio format has the following restrictions:
>
> - Must be a PCM wave file
> - Can only be mono or stereo
> - Must be 8 or 16 bit
> - Sample rate must be between 8,000 Hz and 48,000 Hz

Comment: You can. For example, if you use Silverlight+XNA you can use `MediaElement`. Or, if you work on a Windows Phone 8 project, you can use native code to do that via XAudio2.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Media Element..

```cs
MediaElement MyMedia = new MediaElement();
MyMedia.Source = new Uri("sounds/bag.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
MyMedia.Play();
```

Comment: MediaElement is VERY buggy and not intended for this kind of use. The sound should be in a supported format and should be played through the XNA library